# Is there a way to do filtering with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, properties, mapping, filtering, automapper

Good evening!

I'm currently looking for a way to "filter" an object before sending it to my repository ; that is to say, keeping some properties from the original instance while ignoring or replacing other ones with default values, depending on the context. Indeed, I believe this could be a way to replace all my DTOs, where type conversion is not necessary, while protecting my application against "over-posting", as described on [Brad Wilson's blog](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html).

In other words, what I'm trying to do is replacing:

```
public class UserRegistrationModel {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class UserGenderEditModel {
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

public class User {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public bool IsVIP { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Mapper.CreateMap<UserRegistrationModel, User>()
            .ForMember(d => d.FirstName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.FirstName))
            .ForMember(d => d.Gender, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Gender))
            .ForMember(d => d.IsVIP, o => o.UseValue(false))
            .ForMember(d => d.LastName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.LastName));

        Mapper.CreateMap<UserGenderEditModel, User>()
            .ForMember(d => d.FirstName, o => o.Ignore())
            .ForMember(d => d.Gender, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Gender))
            .ForMember(d => d.IsVIP, o => o.Ignore())
            .ForMember(d => d.LastName, o => o.Ignore());

        var user = Mapper.Map<UserRegistrationModel, User>(new UserRegistrationModel {
            // filling properties
        });
    }
}
```

With something like this (not working of course!):

```
public class User {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public bool IsVIP { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Mapper.CreateMap<User, User>()
            .ForMember(d => d.FirstName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.FirstName))
            .ForMember(d => d.Gender, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Gender))
            .ForMember(d => d.IsVIP, o => o.UseValue(false))
            .ForMember(d => d.LastName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.LastName))
            .ForContext("UserRegistration"); // not real.

        Mapper.CreateMap<User, User>()
            .ForMember(d => d.FirstName, o => o.Ignore())
            .ForMember(d => d.Gender, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Gender))
            .ForMember(d => d.IsVIP, o => o.Ignore())
            .ForMember(d => d.LastName, o => o.Ignore());
            .ForContext("UserGenderEdition"); // not real.

        var user = Mapper.Map<User, User>(new User {
            // filling properties
        }, "UserRegistration"); // not real.
    }
}
```

So, is there a way to achieve that job (not necessarily with AutoMapper)?

Nonetheless, I'm not looking for something directly related to **MVC model binding** mechanism as I would like to reuse that in a web service, or a console app for example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd want to do this but i'd say the best approach here would be to have multiple sub objects which can be used for what you need.

e.g.

```
public class User
{

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Gender
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class UserGender : User
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserGender>()
        .ForMember(d => d.FirstName, o => o.Ignore())
        .ForMember(d => d.Gender, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Gender));
```

You probably don't even have to have the overrides just use the different configs.